# "Kvell" word usage

Tags: word-choice, slang

> I kvell over Zhang Bin's drawings

I'm a bit biased about "kvell" word usage. It is on Urban Dictionary ( http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kvell ), but seems to be pretty rarely-used. In case if "kvell" is not broadly used, what slang word should I use instead "admire" in the following sentence?

> I admire what he does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kvell](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kvell) is from Yiddish and means

> To feel delighted and proud to the point of tears

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/word/word.php?date=Sep-10-2008) gives an example of "kvell over" similar to yours:

> Critics kvelled over the violinist's triumphant return to the stage where she had made her debut many years ago.

You can see that in writing, alternatives like these are much more common than *kvell*:
[image: kvell,acclaim,rejoice,admire,celebrate,appreciate, showing other words more popular than kvell]
*[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kvell,acclaim,rejoice,admire,celebrate,appreciate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of kvell, acclaim, rejoice, admire, celebrate, appreciate; kvell has flatlined here*

Not all of these words can be used with *over*, so if the sense of [delighting in](http://thesaurus.com/browse/delight+in) a particular work is important, have a look at further synonyms. If you're looking for slang, there are plenty of options for an informal context; for example, perhaps you *groove on* a piece of music or *get a kick out of* a painter's unique style.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> "I **dig** what he does."

Comment: Sounds good :) +1

Answer (score -1):

Kvell is a verb(used without objects),slang.
1)to be extraordinarily pleased ; especially to be bursting with pride,as over ones family.
Example
I kvell over Zhang bins drawings

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This answer has already been given, and more completely, by aedia. Please note that StackExchange is a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum, with a specific purposes and format for responses; I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.